# How to prevent android studio from skipping activities?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent, android-activity

I have a quiz app that will save the score on firebase. It works properly. But whenever I try to retake the quiz, it will just show the first activity, and then skip all the activity after it and proceed to the final activity where it shows the output. I checked everything, the IDs are all unique. I can't find where I went wrong.

This is the first part of my quiz. When I retake the quiz, the scores will reset to 0. It works properly. But when I click next, it will just proceed to the final activity where the output is shown.

```
    @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_part1);

firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

phqChoice1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.phqChoice1);
phqChoice2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.phqChoice2);
phqChoice3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.phqChoice3);
phqChoice4 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.phqChoice4);
btnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNext);

getAnswer();

final DatabaseReference myRef = firebaseDatabase.getReference(firebaseAuth.getUid()).child("test");

if (myRef != null) {
    myRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
            result.put("anx", 0);
            result.put("dep", 0);
            myRef.updateChildren(result);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getMessage());
        }
    });


    btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            myRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    UserHistory userHistory = new UserHistory();
                    userHistory.setAnx(anx);
                    userHistory.setDep(dep);
                    myRef.setValue(userHistory);


                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(Part1.this, Part2.class);
                    startActivity(myIntent);
                    finish();
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    System.out.println("Entering data failed. " + databaseError.getMessage());
                }
            });


        }
    });
}}

 private void getAnswer() {
radioGroup1 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
radioGroup1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
        if (checkedId == R.id.phqChoice2) {
            dep++;
        } else if (checkedId == R.id.phqChoice3) {
            dep = dep + 2;
        } else if (checkedId == R.id.phqChoice4) {
            dep = dep + 3;
        }
    }
});}
```

This is the part2 activity where android skips these activities and will just proceed to the final activity if I retake the quiz.

```
     @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_part2);


    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

    btnNext = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnPart2);



    DatabaseReference myRef = firebaseDatabase.getReference(firebaseAuth.getUid()).child("test");
    myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            UserHistory userHistory = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserHistory.class);
            anxHistory = userHistory.getAnx();
            depHistory = userHistory.getDep();

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(Part2.this, databaseError.getCode(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            getAnswer();

                    anxValue = anxHistory + anx;

                    final DatabaseReference myRef = firebaseDatabase.getReference(firebaseAuth.getUid()).child("test");

                    myRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
                            result.put("anx", anxValue);
                            myRef.updateChildren(result);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                            System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getMessage());
                        }
                    });


                Intent part3A = new Intent(Part2.this, Part3.class);
                startActivity(part3A);

        }
    });
}

private void getAnswer() {
    radioGroup2 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup2);
    int selectedItem = radioGroup2.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    if (selectedItem == R.id.part2Choice2) {
        anx++ ;
    } else if (selectedItem == R.id.part2Choice3)  {
        anx = anx + 2 ;
    }
    else if (selectedItem == R.id.part2Choice4) {
        anx = anx + 3;
    }else {
        anx = 0;
    }

        }

}
```

I expect the output to proceed as normally whenever I retake the quiz again. All activities should proceed as usual and no activity should be skipped. What actually happens is the first activity is working properly but all the other activities that are related to the quiz ends up being skipped. Please help. I am clueless and I don't know what else should I check.

In addition, if I click the radio button A (value is 0), the activity will just continue as usual. If I click other buttons which has a value that is greater than 0, (Value is 1-3), and then the activity will just skip to the final activity wherein the output is displayed.

To simplify: Click Radio button A (0) > Next activity, Click Radio Button A(0), > Next Activity (Proceeds as normal.). OR Click Radio button B (1) > Skips other activity, proceeds to the final activity.

Comment: You can edit your Question instead of adding a comment.

Comment: I edited the question. sorry, and thank you @AmitRay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put the intent activity inside the ValueEventListener so whenever I try to enter new data, it will skip to the Final activity. The fix:

```
  myRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                UserHistory userHistory = new UserHistory();
                userHistory.setAnx(anx);
                userHistory.setDep(dep);
                myRef.setValue(userHistory);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                System.out.println("Entering data failed. " + databaseError.getMessage());
            }
        });

Intent myIntent = new Intent(Part1.this, Part2.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);
                finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

try to put the Intent outside the btnNext,onClickListener method

```
Intent part3A = new Intent(Part2.this, Part3.class);
btnNext.setOnClcikListener(){
//here call your intent from Part2

startActivity(part3A);
}
```

Comment: I can't do that. It says variable 'part3A' is accessed from inner class, needs to be declared final.

Comment: just make it final....

if still not working, try to trackdown the activity by adding SOUT in the first line of OnCreate method in Activity two...

Comment: Sorry I have no idea what SOUT means. I'm just starting in android.

Comment: just type "sout" then clcik "TAB" button

sout = system.out.println()

Comment: //activity 2

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     System.out.println("hi....");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_part2);

Comment: u can see the message in LogCat info

Comment: The message that I put in the oncreate in part 2 isn't displayed on the logcat. It will direct to the final activity.